# can i continue with this. is there an inverse direction of modus tollens?

Tags: calculus

[image]

can i continue with this. is there an inverse direction of modus tollens. Should i end this validation like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done well so far! There are two ways to proceed, depending on what rules of inference you're allowed.

1. If you know about contrapositives, then you know that a statement of the form $a \rightarrow b$ is equivalent to the statement $(\lnot b) \rightarrow (\lnot a)$. Using that on the long axiom will finish the problem quickly for you.
2. Otherwise, hopefully you know that a statement of the form $a \rightarrow b$ is equivalent to the statement $(\lnot a) \lor b$, or equivalently to $\lnot(a\land\lnot b)$. Using that transformation on the long axiom will allow you to reach the answer in a few more steps.

Comment: i cant do that few more steps :d can you help me if you have time.

Comment: Are you talking about the second approach?